# Can't get it to provide proper output

Tags: function, powershell

I have this function and I can not get it to work, the $DecimalConversion output is not coming out.. I think I am having some syntax errors.

```
function Get-DecimalNumber(){
$FileCheck = Test-Path "C:\Conversions\conversions.csv"
if($FileCheck){
Do
{
[int]$GetDecimal = Read-host "Write a number between 1-255" | Out-Null
}
while ($GetDecimal -notmatch '\d{1,3}' -or (1..255) -notcontains $GetDecimal)
$DecimalConversion= "{0:X}" -f $GetDecimal
$DecimalConversion
}
else{Write-Warning "Can not find conversions.csv, creating now under C:\Conversions\"; New-Item "C:\Conversions\conversions.csv" -Force | Out-Null}
}
$getfunction=Get-DecimalNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code, I think this looks **better**, let me know what you think!

> `function Get-DecimalNumber {
>       <#
>          .Description
>          The Get-DecimalNumber function gets user input for a decimal number and
>          converts it into hexadecimal and binary numbers. Then this data is added to an
>          excel file (.csv) and the date of conversion is displayed in short form m/d/yyyy.
>       #>
>       $ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'                         #Silences errors
>       $Test = Test-Path "C:\temp\test\conversions.csv"                        #Variable to test path
>       if (! $Test) { #Checking if path does not exist
>           Write-Warning "conversions.csv File Not Present, creating under C:\temp\test\"
>           New-Item 'C:\temp\test\conversions.csv' -Force | Out-Null; break; exit              #Creating path with file & suppressing output
>       }
>       else {
>           [int]$Num = Read-Host "Enter number from 1-255"
>           if ($Num -gt 255 -or $Num -le 1) {
>               Write-Warning "You did not enter a number in the specified range"; break; exit
>           }
>           else {
>               $Hex = [Convert]::ToString($Num, 16)                #Converting from decimal to hexadecimal
>               $Bin = [Convert]::ToString($Num, 2)                 #Converting from decimal to binary
>               Write-Host "Decimal to Hex and Binary:"
>               $NewHashTable1 = @{ }                                           #Creating hashtable
>               $NewHashTable1.Add('Decimal', $Num)                             #Adding values from variables to hash table
>               $NewHashTable1.Add('Hexadecimal', $hex)
>
>               $NewHashTable1.Add('Binary', $bin)
>               $NewHashTable1                                              #Output to screen the previously created hashtable
>               $NewHashTable1 >> "C:\temp\test\conversions.csv"                #Appending hashtable to .csv file
>               Write-Output "'n"
>               Get-Date -Format d                                          #Output date in short format
>               $Now = Get-Date -Format d
>               $Now  >> "C:\temp\test\conversions.csv"                     #Output date to .csv file
>           }
>       }
>   }`

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use a better `while` condition. However, ur issue is caused because of the `out-null` cmdlet on `read-host`.

If you use that, `$GetDecimal` will not get the value you pass in since the `out-null` is processed before the assignment happens. Just remove it. And it should work.

Comment: still cant get it to work.. i took it out but same thing :/

Comment: • Test if the file conversions.csv exists, and if not display a warning message, create it and suppress all output to the console
• Validate user input as an integer (1-255) has been entered. If incorrect input is given display a message and exit.
• Convert the decimal input to hexadecimal and binary using string methods and display the result
•  Send the output to a hash table and append to conversions.csv

Comment: Did you check the value of `$getfunction`? Because thats where you are storing the results of the function. I just did a test again. All i had to do was remove the `| out-null` part and echo the value of `$getfunction`